# Position fixed not working when change iphone screen

Tags: jquery, iphone

I set my header position fixed it is working fine when i change my screen to vertical or horizontal. But only problem when i click on any text box on the page and than i change screen  landscap/portrait my header looks mees. It seems position fixed not working there.

I also added viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Someone can help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. see what i did here,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", function(evt){ 
        var $nav = $(".fixHeader"); //my header class
        $nav.css('position', 'absolute');
        setTimeout(function(){
             $nav.css('position', 'fixed');
           }, 500);
   });
});
```

Thanks, may be this help someone else.